# web3 get sol transfer signatures only for an account?

Tags: transactions, web3.js, sol, getsignaturesforaddress

When attempting to get spl transfers for a specific token you can get the spls token account for an account then from there get recent signatures for transfers of that spl.

Is there a similar functionality for SOL? I am looking to get signatures for SOL only transfers but `getSignaturesForAddress` with a parent account just returns mixed transactions.

Comment: Sorry if this is a nooby question but I have seached through old messages in the Discord and here/stackoverflow with no success.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to filter `getSignaturesForAddress` at call time.  You need to pull down all of the transactions and inspect them client side